# How to compute the variance of the following expression?

Tags: variance, random-variable

I have a complicated function that looks like this.

$$ L = \sum_{m = 1}^{M} \left|\frac{\sin\left(N\frac{x_m}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x_m}{2}\right)}\right|^2 + \sum_{p = 1, p \neq q}^{M}\sum_{q = 1, q \neq p}^{M} \frac{\sin\left(N\frac{x_p}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x_p}{2}\right)} \frac{\sin\left(N\frac{x_q}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x_q}{2}\right)} \cos\left( (1 - N) \frac{x_p - x_q}{2} + \beta_q - \beta_p \right) $$

Where, $x$ are distributed with standard normal distribution $x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, $p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2} \right)$. The $\beta$ are uniformly distributed from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. $\beta \sim \mathcal{U}[-\pi, +\pi]$, $p(\beta) = \frac{1}{2\pi}$.

I wanted to compute the expectation and the variance of this expression.  I have a closed form expression for the expectation and let's call it $D$ and it looks like the following.

$$ D = \mathbb{E}[L] =  M \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(x)  \left|\frac{\sin\left(N\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right|^2 dx   $$

The expectation of the second term vanishes because the $\beta$ are uniformly distributed.

However, when I want to compute the variance, I am a bit confused. Should it be like the following?

$$ \mathbb{V}[L] = M^2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(x)  \left|\frac{\sin\left(N\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right|^4 dx - D^2 + \frac{M^2}{4\pi^2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \left[ \frac{\sin\left(N\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \frac{\sin\left(N\frac{y}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)} \cos\left( (1 - N) \frac{x - y}{2} + u - v \right) \right]^2 p(x) p(y) du dv dx dy  $$

I didn't write the covariance of the two terms because I assume that would be $0$ because the expression will contain a cosine with $\beta$ in it. Am I right in expressing the variance like this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your expectation is missing a factor of 2.

The double sum ($\sum_{p=1}^M \sum_{q=1}^M$...) contains $M(M-1)$ terms where $p \neq q$, which have expectation 0 for the reason you pointed out, but also $M$ terms with $p=q$. These simplify to
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\left(\frac{\sin(N\frac{x}2)}{\sin(\frac{x}2)}\right)^2 dx  $$
because the cosine term is 1, and you end up with
$$
\mathbb{E}(L) = 2M \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\left(\frac{\sin(N\frac{x}2)}{\sin(\frac{x}2)}\right)^2 dx
$$

You need a similar approach for the variance, i.e. consider the covariance between the first term and the second term when $p=q$, as this will probably be non-zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually forgot to mention that the second term  has the condition that $p \neq q$. I am editing it.